# can guice create a factory for me?

Tags: java, guice, factory

I have the following factory class:

```
public class MessagePresenterCreator implements IPresenterFactory{
    @Override
    public MessagePresenter createPresenter(Message m) {
        if (m instanceof Letter) {
            return new LetterPresenter();
        }
        if (m instanceof Cable) {
            return new CablePresenter();
        }
        if (m instanceof Postcard) {
            return new PostcardPresenter();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Can I configure a guice to auto-generate and supply such factory by the following interface:

```
public interface IPresenterFactory {
    public abstract MessagePresenter createPresenter(Message m);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if Guice can work out the logic required to turn a message into a message presenter? Then no.

Comment: I am asking if I can configure a guice module that will map Letter->LetterPresenter etc' and guice will create the factory for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No guice does not have a factory like that built in. You could write a factory that took a `Map<Class<? extends Message>, Class<? extends MessagePresenter>` and have that use reflection. That way you can manage it in a guice module if that is your goal.

```
public class MessagePresenterCreator implements IPresenterFactory{
    private final Map<Class<? extends Message>, Class<? extends MessagePresenter> mapping;
    public MessagePresenterCreator(Map<Class<? extends Message>, Class<? extends MessagePresenter> mapping) {
         this.mapping = mapping;
    }

    @Override
    public MessagePresenter createPresenter(Message m) {
       Class<? extends MessagePresenter> clazz = mapping.get(m);
       if (clazz == null) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
       }
       return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I like to think of factories in two ways - factories that merely assemble objects from components, and factories that do conditional logic in that assembly.

Your factories have logic behind them.  Guice can't automate that logic, because it simply handles the wiring up of dependencies.  If you have a type that is created that needs some amount of injected dependencies and some things that are provided just at creation time, then the auto-wiring of factories can be done with guice's [AssistedInject extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject).  This would let you give a factory interface, annotate any fields in the created type with @AssistedInject, and guice's extension would create a factory implementation class which would inject anything bound in the Injector, and also pass through those create() parameters.  But in such a case, all Guice and AssistedInject are doing is pulling pieces together - wiring things up according to a recipe specified in advance.  It's not making decisions about them at the last minute.

You're providing conditional creation of objects.  That's not going to work.

[An idea above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9925727/337516) mentions making a factory that depends on mapping of type to presenter - something like:

```
Map<Class<? extends Message>, Class<? extends MessagePresenter>>
```

This is a good approach, if you combine it with Multibinder's [MapBindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings). (I gotta beef up those docs... hmm)

With this approach you can create an extensible factory - defining the initial mappings of Message -> MessagePresenter subclasses, but leave the possibility open for additional mappings later without having to change your factory - just bind more mappings on the multibinder, like so:

```
 MapBinder<String, Snack> mapbinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(
     binder(), 
     new TypeLiteral<Class<? extends Message>>(){}, 
     new TypeLiteral<Class<? extends MessagePresenter>>(){});
 mapbinder.addBinding(MyMessage.class).toInstance(MyMessagePresenter.class);
 mapbinder.addBinding(YourMessage.class).toInstance(YourMessagePresenter.class);
```

And you can do this in as many modules as you like, adding more types between which to switch, using the mapping.

Comment: hmmm, I am trying to do that with binding the Map<String, Provider<Snack>> and it is not working at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833777/guice-multibinder-with-providers  I love the feature but can't seem to get it to work.