# guice multibinder with Providers

Tags: guice

I am trying to be able to have this in my code

```
@Inject
private Map<String, Provider<Processor>> providers;
```

I was trying but this code does not compile

```
MapBinder<String, Provider<Processor>> mapbinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder, String.class, Provider<Processor>.class);
mapbinder.addBinding("splineV1Beta").to(SplineProcessor.class);
mapbinder.addBinding("invertV1Beta").to(InvertProcessor.class);
```

This code fails on startup in that it can't bind my Map

```
MapBinder<String,Processor> mapbinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder, String.class, Processor.class);
mapbinder.addBinding("splineV1Beta").to(SplineProcessor.class);
mapbinder.addBinding("invertV1Beta").to(InvertProcessor.class);
```

How do I setup the bindings correctly here?

NOTE: I am looking for something easy too so developers just add one line every time we have a new processor.(I am hoping I don't have to add one line + some factory interface...should be a way, but I have tried other things in addition to above with TypeLiteral and toProvider() method as well).

MORE INFO: okay, I found out if I have the below line(but do not call addBinding at all) Guice will actually startup which is good, but all the addBinding().to method signatures are now wrong as they want a

```
Provider<? extends Provider<Processor>>
//This below line ends up with mabbinder2.addBinder().to() wanting the above param type?
MapBinder<String, Provider<Processor>> mapbinder2 = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder, stringLit, list);
```

RADICALLY change my thinking and I try injecting something like this(hoping that map.get("xxx") creates new instances every time...

```
@Inject
private Map<String, Processor> providers;
```

and I bound it like this but unfortunately, the map is always returning the same instance :(...

```
MapBinder<String, Processor> mapbinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder, String.class, Processor.class);
mapbinder.addBinding("splineV1Beta").toProvider(new TypeLiteral<Provider<SplineProcessor>>() {;});
mapbinder.addBinding("invertV1Beta").toProvider(new TypeLiteral<Provider<InvertProcessor>>() {;});
```

EDIT: according to this doc http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html you can have a

```
 MapBinder<String, Snack> and inject a Map<String, Provider<Snack>>
```

but when I do that(with a private field), I get the following....(whereas when I change to my other solution but don't call mapbinder.addBinding, it binds and works just fine)...

```
1) No implementation for java.util.Map<java.lang.String,    
javax.inject.Provider<controllers.modules2.framework.Processor>> was bound.
```

Do I have to use constructor injection for this to work like their example?  I am in an abstract class so that would be very inconvenient to change 10 classes :(.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2):

Though Guice seems to be very good about using JSR-330 annotations interchangeably, it seems that Multibindings hides the `Provider` type within a `Map` and therefore may be expecting to inject a `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.google.inject.Provider<...>>` instead. I haven't been able to reproduce your problem, but try that and see if it helps.

Side note: If you want to avoid changing it in code everywhere, you can hackishly bind a provider of `Map<String, javax.inject.Provider<Foo>>` to something that takes in the multibinder-created `Map<String, com.google.inject.Provider<Foo>>`. If I'm right and this is the problem, you can fix it one place rather than bouncing between `javax.inject` and `com.google.inject` everywhere.

Comment: You can also upgrade to Guice 4 to get the fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Map<String, Provider<Processor>>` at the injection point, the way to bind it is:

`MapBinder<String, Processor> mapbinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder, String.class, Processor.class);
mapbinder.addBinding("splineV1Beta").to(SplineProcessor.class);
mapbinder.addBinding("invertV1Beta").to(InvertProcessor.class);`

You would use `toProvider()` if you are supplying a custom provider, which you are not, i.e. you are merely trying to use the implicit underlying provider.