# how to have guice use my factory for creating new instances

Tags: guice

I am trying to have guice call my factory method to create the instance and then fill it in from inspecting it's annotations.  I know I have done this before but I can't figure out how to bind the following code....

My bind code

```
binder.bind(ProcessorFactory.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

The code I am binding (and I want Guice to fill in SplineProcessor and InvertProcessor with their bindings on creation.

```
public class ProcessorFactory implements Provider<Processor>{

    public static final ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    private Map<String, Class<?>> nameToClazz = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

    public ProcessorFactory() {
        nameToClazz.put("splineV1Beta", SplineProcessor.class);
        nameToClazz.put("invertV1Beta", InvertProcessor.class);
}

    @Override
    public Processor get() {
        String moduleName = threadLocal.get();
        if(moduleName == null)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please call ProcessorFactory.threadLocal.set(moduleName)");
        Class<?> clazz = nameToClazz.get(moduleName);
        if(clazz == null)
             return null;

    try {
        Object newInstance = clazz.newInstance();
        return (Processor) newInstance;
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        threadLocal.set(null);
    }
}

}
```

NOTE: I would STILL like to know how to do this though I also have this open question which is an even better way of doing the same thing [guice multibinder with Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833777/guice-multibinder-with-providers)

but unfortunately, I can't get that to work either.

NOTE: What inject code do I use as well.  I am using the following code to inject(and tried ProcessorFactory as well).

```
@Inject
private Provider<ProcessorSetup> processors;
```

EDIT FOR MORE CLARIY

In a bean I have the following

```
@Inject
private Provider<ProcessorSetup> processors;
```

and when I call processors.get(), it steps into guice and then guice correctly invokes ProcessorFactory.get() and I step through that code, and my new enttiy passes through Guice to be returned to the client but is never wired up to anything.  This stinks because we have @Inject in those entities we create as well.  I know about 2 years ago I had this working on another project related to these posts

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/google-guice/dean/google-guice/BZn2cnSeX64/MCRgFPjoHH4J

as I did figure out how to remove the injector at one point finally.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my new enttiy passes through Guice to be returned to the client but is never wired up to anything. This stinks because we have @Inject in those entities we create as well

This is as expected, since you create the class using `clazz.newInstance()`. If you want Guice to inject it's members you need to call `injector.injectMemebers(newInstance)`. 
This will inject all fields and methods, but obviously not constructor injections.

I also second condit suggestion to replace the ThreadLocals with AssitedInject for parameter passing, or simply create a custom factory instead of a Provider.

Comment: hmmm, I thought this worked previously without having the injector...darn.  I do need to try out the assisted inject and post questions on that when I have problems as well.

Comment: The only thing that might have worked are static injections (but I don't think this is what you want).

For a simple example of custom factory you can check how Guartz (Guice + Quartz) implemented it.

http://code.google.com/p/slurry/source/browse/quartz4guice/trunk/src/main/java/org/slurry/quartz4guice/internal/InjectorJobFactory.java

Comment: nice, you can inject the Injector...I didn't think/know that was possible.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get Guice to use your provider to create instances of `Processor`? If so then you should change your configuration to something like:

```java
bind(Processor.class).toProvider(ProcessorFactory.class);
```

It also looks like you're using that `ThreadLocal` to configure the resulting instances. Have you considered [Assisted Inject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject)?

Comment: I have always gotten confused with their examples as they don't show all the code and skip stuff in places.  I really want to use MultiMapBinder but that was not working as it fit like a glove in this situation.

Comment: hmmm, that didn't seem to work.  I added to my question that I modified my inject to Inject private Provider<ProcesorSetup> processors and I see Guice correlty insantiate the class and I get a new class BUT that class does not get wired up from his @Inject annotations at all for some reason....weird.

Comment: I shoudl note in the debugger, Guice correctly calls into my Factory under the Guice framework, but the object I pass back is not injected with Guice stuff(and it used to be on an old project I did....I don't know why it is not injecting stuff after I create it).

Comment: Are you using the `Provider` in the question? If so, then you're creating the objects, not Guice.

Comment: added EDIT FOR MORE CLARITY section in the question.